# How to implement abstract method with different number of parameters

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overloading, overriding

I have four classes, one is an abstract class and two are derived classes.
in abstract class I have the method edit, which holds 4 parameters I want my derived classes to have the same method but with different number of parameters.

The code for abstract class Animal

```
public abstract class Animal {

protected String name;
protected String color;
protected String diet;
protected String habitat; }

public abstract void Edit(String name, String color, String diet, String habitat);
```

Code for derived class dog

```
public class Dog extends Animal {

private String temperament;
private String breed; }

public void Edit(String name, String color, String diet, String habitat, String temperament, String breed) {

    setName(name);
    setColor(color);
    setDiet(diet);
    setHabitat(habitat);
    setTemperament(temperament);
    setBreed(breed);
}
```

Code for derived class bird

```
public class Bird extends Animal {
private String feather; }

public void Edit(String name, String color, String diet, String habitat,   String feather) {

    setName(name);
    setColor(color);
    setDiet(diet);
    setHabitat(habitat);
    setFeather(feather);
}
```

I get an error in my derived classes, I need this abstract method as I need to use it in my AnimalList class as seen bellow:

```
public class AnimalList {

ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();

public void EditDog(String strName, String name, String color, String diet, String habitat, String temperament, String breed){
    for(int i=0; i<animals.size();i++){
        if (animals.get(i) instanceof Dog){
            if(animals.get(i).getName().equals(name))
            {
               animals.get(i).Edit(name, color, diet, habitat, temperament, breed);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void EditBird(String strName, String name, String color, String diet, String habitat, String feather){
    for(int i=0; i<animals.size();i++){
        if (animals.get(i) instanceof Bird){
            if(animals.get(i).getName().equals(name))
            {
               animals.get(i).Edit(name, color, diet, habitat, feather);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In concrete class that extends from abstract class you MUST implement all abstract methods that was not implemented. If you really don't want method Edit() from Animal class to be implemented use `public abstract void Edit(String name, String color, String diet, String habitat) {}`

But this shows to bad class design. You should reconsider your Object design.

Comment: The issue here is that you are trying to cram all of your Setters into one method called "Edit".

Comment: Seems that you need *Builder* pattern.

Comment: One way is to use the `Object... args` syntax to make a variable argument length method...

Comment: You can use Fluent Interface. http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the method `Edit` is in fact different for every kind of derived class and you must check what kind of class the object in the list is (and you do that in `if (animals.get(i) instanceof Dog){...}`) then that means your method is not generic = not applicable for all animals. So I think it doesn't make sense to have an abstract method. All derived abstract classes must have the same signature (name and number of parameters) as the method declared in superclass.

Implement separate Edit method for Dog, Bird... and cast an Animal for applicable class in every `if(...)`

```
if (animals.get(i) instanceof Dog){
    if(animals.get(i).getName().equals(name))
    {
         ((Dog) animals.get(i)).Edit(name, color, diet, habitat, temperament, breed);
    }
}
```